# Java program to find the second smallest number in console input

Tags: java, eclipse

I am really trying to grasp this problem but could not continue further without help.
My logic is in order but for some reason it will not execute properly.

On execution I want to enter a line of numbers for example 10 12 5 9 3 and the program should return me the second smallest number.
As I want to control the basics first I am refraining from using any other imported classes except for the two used.

If someone could shed some light on why this does not work I would be very grateful.

```
package secondSmallest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class secondSmallest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);
    
    int smallest = 1;
    int secsmallest = 0;
    int hold = 0;
    
    while(scan.hasNext()); {
        
        hold = scan.nextInt();
        
        if (hold < smallest) {
            smallest = secsmallest;
            smallest = hold;
            
            
        } else {
            hold = scan.nextInt();
        }
        
    out.printf(" %d", secsmallest);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have smallest = 1? just read all your input in a list, sort it, and get the element with index 1

Comment: When, do you think, your input stream will stop receiving potential data?

Comment: You can single step through your program with a debugger to see exactly where it goes wrong.

Comment: You init secsmallest to something smaller than smallest. I smell a trap there.

Comment: What makes you think that "this does not work"? What are the symptoms?

Comment: if you replace `smallest = secsmallest;` by `secsmallest=smallest;`you will get closer to your solution. Otherwise you just overwrite smallest but never change secsmallest.

Comment: and what if smallest < hold < secssmallest ? Then hold should become the new secsmallest. This is missing in your logic.

Comment: Why are you using PrintStream rather than just System.out.println/printf?

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

> My logic is in order but for some reason it will not execute properly.

means that your logic is not in order (unless there is just a typo, or other syntax error, blocking flawless result);

---

Second:

[`Scanner#hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()), which you have as a `while` condition:

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

and you should, somewhere, somehow, indicate when you want your `while` loop to end. In your example, your loop is going on *infinitely*, as it does not have any base case. Even the "Enter" keystroke is a data, and pressing it will keep entering new-line control character;

---

Third:

You have your smallest initialized as `1`, which is not really a clean design to statically assign the constant to the current minimum. Think of a possibility when your input is different;

---

Fourth:

You are printing the `secsmallest` inside your while loop, which, I suppose, is not what you meant to do;

---

Fifth:

By reading in your `else` block `hold = scan.nextInt();` you are effectively ommiting one input, as the moment your while iterates one step forward, you have another `hold = scan.nextInt(); and you jump one iteration`;

---

Sixth:

There are many ways to design "find-second-smallest" algorithm (sorting it first and then taking the second element; introducing two pointers; etc.), but if you insist to follow something close to your way, this works as expected:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {10, 12, 5, 9, 32, 5, 123, 4, -34, 12, -534, -53, -1, 432, 53};
        int res = secondSmallest(arr);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    public static int secondSmallest(int[] arr) {
        int smallest = arr[0];
        int secsmallest = arr[1];
        int i = 2;
        while (i < arr.length-1) {
            int current = arr[i];
            if (current < smallest) {
                 secsmallest = smallest;
                 smallest = current;
            }
            else if(current < secsmallest) {
                secsmallest = current;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return secsmallest;
    }
}
```

Outputting:

```
-53
```

Comment: Valid remarks but the code does not add a lot: You ignord completely the scanner and the same comment for you: "what if smallest < current < secssmallest ? Then current should become the new secsmallest. This is missing in your logic"

Comment: I, deliberately, present the code with predefined array, to explicitly show on what data the algorithm I presented works. Ran over 5 long unit tests and it does not fail anywhere. *"what if smallest < current < secssmallest ?* - so what? what is broken in this case? smallest should always be < secsmallets. Can you provide a sample data where this will not work?

Comment: Off course your range works because the second smallest is just behind the smallest. Try it with `{10, 12, -53, 5, 9, 32, 5, 123, 4, -34, 12, -534, -1, 432, 53}` and you will get `-1`.

Comment: @Conffusion good catch, thank you, and thanks to Grey.

Answer (score -1):

Your program should look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int secSmallest = smallest;
    int hold = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        hold = scan.nextInt();
        if (hold < smallest) {
            secSmallest = smallest;
            smallest = hold;
        } else if (hold < secSmallest) secSmallest = hold;
    }
    out.printf(" %d", secSmallest);
}
```